# Get user created events Graph API syntax

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to retrieve the user created events by Facebook Graph Api .I have given the permissions has user_events in scope ,and have the syntax as $events = $facebook->api('/me/events');
But this is returning an empty array ?Can anyone sort the problem pls??

Comment: Any one there to answer this question?